# Falta um espaço ao reverter revisão de edição

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização, edição

Veja as [revisões de edição desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/246808/revisions).

Na revisão 5 fiz uma reversão para a revisão 3. Automaticamente o detalhamento da edição ficou assim:

> Reversão para edição3

Faltando um espaço. O correto seria:

> Reversão para edição 3

Comment: Consertei no transifex https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/96588173?qt=reversão acho que é só esperar um novo build do site agora

Comment: @Math Alguém da _staff_ ainda precisa aprovar, mas obrigado mesmo assim =D

Comment: @LINQ isso msm, o JNat aprovou agora

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corrigido pelo @Math no [Transifex](http://transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B_BR/) e aprovado pelo @JNat.

Pode ver [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4526/revisions).