# Ao editar wiki de tag a tradução de "plain text" é "texto plano"

Tags: debate, localização

[image]

Ao editar wiki de tags existe um texto que diz para não utilizar formatação Markdown, pois não é suportado nesse contexto. A tradução de "plain text" aqui foi "texto plano".

Na minha opinião "texto plano" não dá a mesma ideia que "plain text" e seria melhor inteligível se fosse "texto simples".

Uma outra ideia é tirar o "plano" e deixar algo assim:

> (somente texto, sem formatação Markdown)

O que acham?

Comment: Particularmente, IMHO, acho que texto plano já é compreensível. Da mesma maneira de que se usa, no contexto de armazenamento de senhas em "*texto plano*" e todos entendem, acho que não haveria a necessidade de mudar para "*somente texto*" nos wikis de tag... Mas, é só opinião.

Comment: De fato 'texto plano' soa estranho, mas para mim 'texto puro' seria mais apropriado do que 'texto simples'.

Answer (score 3):

Concordo em deixar "somente texto".

Mas tem que pedir pra algum moderador alterar, porque usuários normais não podem alterar *strings* que já foram revisadas.

Por exemplo: Essa é uma *string* **que não tem tradução**, portanto, nunca foi revisada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é uma *string* que já é traduzida, **portanto já foi revisada**. Porém [estava com um erro](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6445/18246), que já foi corrigido pelo Math.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nas versões anteriores o [sistema mostrava um erro, do tipo](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/57786?m=37298595#37298595)

> *Você não tem permissão para alterar strings revisadas*

Neste caso é possível adicionar como sugestão. Masssssss isso não vai pra fila de *strings* a serem revisadas. Outra vez eu pedi pro Gabe pra ele revisar algumas *strings* e [ele disse que não haviam *strings*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/57786?m=37287234#37287234) para revisar.

Comment: Transifex não faz?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, tem que pedir pra algum moderador alterar no transifex. Isso porque não é possível, para usuários normais, sugerir alterações para strings revisadas.

Comment: Eu não sei se entendi, mas o que quero dizer é que qualquer um pode participar do transifex, e só aguardar a aprovação lá, não necessariamente precisaria esperar um moderador aqui, mas sim esperar só a " triagem". Mas é claro que faz muito tempo que não uso a ferramenta e não sei se entendi o que você quis dizer.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sendo mais claro: usuários normais **não podem sugerir alterações** para strings revisadas. Ou seja, tudo que já foi aceito só pode ser alterado por alguém que tenha permissões elevadas.

Comment: Ah, agora entendi, eu acho, as strings que já passaram por isto não podem passar novamente, é isso? Não lembrava desta "limitação".

Comment: Também fazia tempo que não usava a ferramenta então estou em dúvida, mas até onde me vem na memória qualquer um pode sugerir edições, tipo na fila de análises aqui, depois alguém com mais permissão aprova elas. Vou gastar um tempinho depois com isso pra tentar refrescar na memória pq já não me lembro mais desses detalhes

Comment: Sobre o "concordo", é com o "texto simples" ou com o "somente texto"? O AP fez duas sugestões na pergunta

Comment: @Math foi o que pensei, que qualquer um poderia fazer, por isso que tudo isso me soa estranho.

Comment: @Math Editei a resposta

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Editei a resposta

Comment: @Math Ficou claro?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ficou claro?

Comment: Sim, então realmente precisa de uma permissão mais elevada para sugerir edições no transifex, e permissão mais elevada ainda para aceitá-las. Certo?